# Select Value from Dropdown with Apostrophe

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the selected value from a dropdown. The value is "St. John's". When using

```
$('#dropdown').val()
```

I get "St. John" without the apostrophe or the s. I've tried using several suggestions from other pages without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EEL6u/

Comment: You should always provide relevant HTML markup for this kind of question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option in your select list is incorrectly delimited:

```
<select>
    <option value='St. John's'>St. John's</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Exactly right. I thought it might be a way to resolve from the list that was already populated. Evidently I needed to go to the source. Although @volkan helped me out, your answer was the closest to answering my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

make sure you use double quotes for your option tag. if you use single quotes, your qoutes in value will break the syntax.

```
<option selected value= "St John's"></option>
```

Comment: yet another reason to always use double quotes for HTML attribute values

Comment: @jbabey You obviously don't have customers like ours, who put ' and " in product titles to denote feet and inches.  The only real answer is to escape every value before you create the option tag.

Comment: I'm not sure where the values are populated at this point. If I type $('#dropdown').text(), I get -- > SELECT ONEAlleganyAnne ArundelArlington, VABaltimoreBaltimore CityCalvertCarolineCarrollCecilCharlesDorchesterFairfax, VAFrederickGarrettHarfordHowardKentLoudon, VAMontgomeryPrince George'sPrince William, VAQueen Anne'sSomersetSt. John'sTalbotWashingtonWashington DCWicomicoWorcester

Comment: Based on this information, does it still appear to be where it is being populated?

Comment: maybe post (edit your question) your relevant html+javascript so we can actually see how the select is populated?

Comment: I found where it is populated, and this is the format: <option value='St. John's'>St. John's</option> It is obviously to do with the value using single quotes. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Most likelythe HTML code for the `option` is wrong. If you are using apostrophes around the value, and don't escape the text inside it correctly, the value will end at the apostrope in the text:

```
<option value='St. John's'>St. John's</option>
                        ^
                        The rest is outside the value
```

If you use quotation marks, apostrophes is not a problem:

```
<option value="St. John's">St. John's</option>
```

If you escape the apostrophe, it also works:

```
<option value='St. John&#39;s'>St. John's</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're delimiting the option tag's value attribute with a single quote.

Try surrounding `$('#dropdown').val()` with `alert()`, or look at the the output in the console after surrounding it with `console.log()` to make sure you're not losing the rest of it because of the way you're outputting the value.

If you post the rest of your code, it might help us troubleshoot.